# Adding switch/outlet receptacle to 20 amp circuit

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, receptacle, water-heater

I put a power vent water heater in basement, and only nearby outlet is GFCI (for a rarely used sump pump) that I'm told is not code for the power vent blower.

There is a nearby dedicated non-gfci circuit for an even rarer used radon mitigation blower.  Previous owner got upsold from a basement waterproofer, I've done 3 tests, no radon, so I usually have it off. Since the wire goes outside a few inches to the radon fan box, they used 12-2 UF-B on a 20 amp breaker. I'd like to keep the radon fan since it's handy to vent my utility room after dusty boiler cleanings.

Can I put a duplex switch/outlet receptacle on that line (I should have enough slack), with the radon fan on the switch, and the water heater in the outlet.  The W/H blower is rated at 5 amps, and the radon fan is likely in that range.  Can just put a simple 15 amp 2-in-1, or do I need to find a 20 amp version?

Comment: Need to check the power requirements of the radon fan. You can't have receptacles on a circuit that has >50% of capacity used by hardwired stuff. And for stuff like this that would be derated to 80%. So with 20A that means if radon > 8A then you can't put a receptacle. But if that's the case if you can hardwire w/h blower and total of the two is <= 16A then you're OK.

Comment: thanks.  I'm looking an it seems most of these radon system don't pull more than 3amps, so I think I'll be okay, but will verify.

Comment: ....what? Can you get an actual chapter-and-verse Code cite (NEC/CEC, IRC/NBCC, or a local ordinance/bylaw amending the Codes) for the water heater power vent blower not being permitted to be on a GFCI, or the sump pump requiring a *dedicated* circuit for that matter?

Comment: It's in the W/H manual to NOT put on GFCI.  Maybe not code.  Don't think sump and batt backup need to be dedicated, but it's kind of a long stretch to get W/H plugged in (plus I need to add an extender to get all three plugged in.  Figure that would be something that might trigger a home purchase inspector.  Thought it'd look cleaner to have W/H tied in to the radon system since the wire run right over it.

Comment: NEC 110.3(B) says (UL/CSA/ETL) Listed equipment shall be installed per the Instructions. This section is normally accepted as overriding the following NEC sections. You would likely need to add the unprotected receptacle and leave the protected in place to protect the sump (if allowed to share per fastened-in-place rules mentioned above). I'm also confused how you think adding a receptacle to your radon circuit in basement would not be subject to gfci requirement in basements?

Comment: Hm, didn't know you needed GFCI for unfinished basement space. So just better to hardwire the W/H blower onto the radon line, and maybe add a switch a bit down so I can toggle the radon fan as needed?  I'm guessing snipping the power cords on water heater voids warranty, but oh well.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is, it's cord-and-plug connected.  Appliance instructions can say "don't plug it into GFCI" and you have to follow that, but they can't say "remove GFCI receptacle protection where Code requires it". Because receptacles are general-use.  It's a catch-22 which they created at your expense.  Only recourse I see is to send it back with a vengeance, but I would talk to the AHJ about if there's an option to do it legally.  AHJ needs to approve the circuit in any case.